# How do normal components detect Mouse Events

Tags: java, swing, accessibility

For example, how do `JList`s get `MouseEvent`s? And how should I create my own `Component`'s `MouseListener`?

The official `JList`s, `JButton`s, `JCheckBox`es and other `swing` components aren't using `MouseListener`s are they? What do they use, and what should I use if I'm in the making of one? (Possibly with `accessibility` support)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official components use the normal listeners (MouseListerner, ComponentListener, FocusListener and so on) but you do not immediately see it, as it is all encapsulated in the Look&Feel UI classes. E.g. for JList have a look inside BasicListUI, and you will find the appropriate listeners.

For your custom components, it usually is enough to implement the listeners directly. However, if you also want to support pluggable look and feel, you may have to go through greater lengths and supply a UI implementation for each look and feel separately, just as the standard jre-components do.

Answer (score 1):

your component must extends `JComponent` and implement `MouseListener`

These are the methods you must override:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

from an accessibility perspective, the methods you must implement depend on the role of the element as exposed to the accessibility API. For a button, you must implement the `mouseClicked` handler because this is what the accessibility API will attempt to dispatch.